# Is there a yii2 equivalent to zend1 fetchAssoc?

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii2

I am trying to upgrade a zend1 site to yii2, and the table models frequently use fetchAssoc to get records from the database with the ID column as the array key.  Is there a yii2 equivalent?

Example:
PHP

```
$query = table::find()                
    ->select(['id',
         'firstName',
         'lastName'
    ])->indexBy('id'); //no effect?

$command = $query->createCommand();

$results = $command->queryAll();
```

Datebase contains

```
[
    [
       id=>15
       firstName=>"fname",
       lastName=>"lname"
    ],
    [
       id=>16
       firstName=>"fname2",
       lastName=>"lname2"
    ]
]
```

I want it to return as

```
[
    15=>
       [
          id=>15
          firstName=>"fname",
          lastName=>"lname"
       ],
    16=>
       [
          id=>16
          firstName=>"fname2",
          lastName=>"lname2"
       ]
]
```

instead of

```
[
    0=>
       [
          id=>15
          firstName=>"fname",
          lastName=>"lname"
       ],
    1=>
       [
          id=>16
          firstName=>"fname2",
          lastName=>"lname2"
       ]
]
```

If I add

```
$results=array_combine(array_column($results,key($results[0])), $results);
```

That creates the index, but I would prefer to use the framework to do it.

Thanks

Comment: could be you need  only a simple asArray() from your find() ..

Comment: That didn't seem to have any affect.  I am starting to think it's indexBy, just trying to figure out how to use it

Comment: you should add  some sample and the expected  result  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it, it needs asArray(true) and indexBy('column name or function') and then call all, or column, or one.

```
$results = table::find()->asArray(true)->indexBy('id')->all()
```

I was previously using

```
$command = $query->createCommand();
$results = $command->queryAll();
```

Final code example:

```
$query = table::find()                
    ->select(['id',
         'firstName',
         'lastName'
    ])->indexBy('id')->asArray(true);
$results=$query->all();
```